# AlwaysOn - Targetting a Read-Only Replica with Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 SP2 environment that uses AlwaysOn for HA.  I am trying to target the read-only replica from other SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 instances using linked servers.  I have installed the SQL Native Client 11.0, and tried everything (OLEDB for ODBC, OLEDB, etc.) to get them to work, but am running into issues.  Either they don't route to the replica, or the connection doesn't support basic data types.  I know the read-only routing is working, because OSQL tests proved successful.

Has anyone made this work?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2008 ,

You need to

1. Install ODBC 17 drivers
2. create a DSN using odbc17 driver to your listener
3. create a linked server with above dsn as a datasource.

### For Higher SQL serer version you use similar code to create linked server

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'<MY_RO_linkedserver>', 
@srvproduct=N'SQL', 
@provider=N'SQLNCLI11', 
@datasrc=N'<AON_listener,port>', 
@provstr=N'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly; MultiSubnetFailover=Yes; User ID=xyz', 
@catalog=N'<DB_NAme>'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MY_RO_linkedserver', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'MY_RO_linkedserver', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'MY_RO_linkedserver', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'True', @rmtuser = N''
GO
```